# Skipping Android Studio AndroidManifest merging errors due to minSDK and targetSDK version mismatches

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio throws build errors when the minSDKVersions of main and library projects do not match, during merging process of AndroidManifest files..
This means I have to revisit the minSDKVersion/targetSDKVersion my app supports and have a unified versions across my project libraries....Is there someway I can force Android studio to skip this version checks during manifest merging?﻿

**[Error format]**

Main manifest has uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion=x but library uses targetSdkVersion=y

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're having problems with a library having a higher minSdkVersion than the app that includes it? If so, the build breakage is  by design -- the intent is that the app developer should be made aware of the problem and consciously do something about it. It would be bad to just silently increase the app's minSdkVersion to match the highest value found in one of the libraries.

There's a discussion at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/e656VuS3BtM

Having said that, we're currently working on revamping manifest merging, so it's possible this will change at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Yes you're right! My project has multiple library dependencies most of them with a higher minSDK version. Would be great if the Android tools team comes up with some option of "knowingly" ignoring the higher minSDK versions for libraries..else porting to Android Studio would mean a whole lot of revamping for existing apps. Thanks, looking forward to hearing more on this thread!